# Mysql And php Select only show first word

Tags: php, mysql, space

Hello Friends I have a problem with my php page and Mysql, I run this setence for example "Select name from articles" and it´s work ok but when a name of one article has the following structure it doesn´t work for example.

if the name of the article it´s "Bike" it´s work ok but if the name is "blank bike" it only show blank not "blank bike" i think that it´s happend because the words are separate for blank space, how can i repair it?

I am showing this data in a form using

```
<?php
include "./include/conexionbd.php";

// Consulta

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT USUARIO.NOMBRE,USUARIO.APELLIDOS,INCIDENCIAS.TITULO,INCIDENCIAS.DESCRIPCION,INCIDENCIAS.FECHA_ENTRADA,USUARIO.Departamento FROM INCIDENCIAS INNER JOIN USUARIO ON USUARIO.ID_USUARIO=INCIDENCIAS.ID_USUARIO WHERE INCIDENCIAS.ID_INCIDENCIAS=$_GET[infosin]");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
    echo '<form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Titulo Incidencia</label>';
    echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='titulo' readonly='readonly' value=$row[2]>";
    echo "<label>Tecnico Asignado</label>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='descripcion' readonly='readonly' value='Sin TÃ©cnico Asignado'>";
    echo "<label>Usuario de la Incidencia</label>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='descripcion' readonly='readonly' value=$row[0]>";
    echo "<label>Departamento del Usuario</label>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='Departamento' readonly='readonly' value=$row[5]>";
    echo '<label>DescripciÃ³n</label></br>';
    echo "<textarea class='form-control' rows='10' name='descripcion' readonly='readonly' value=descripcion>$row[3]</textarea>";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</form>';
    };
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yeah, show us your current full code.

Comment: ok i just uploaded the php code the problem is in the first input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the `$row[x]` inside `{` and `}`

Also for html you must put the values between apostrophes `'` and `'`

So:

```
echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' name='titulo' readonly='readonly' value='{$row[2]}'>";
```

Or you can chain them as follows:

```
echo"<input type='text' class='form-control' name='titulo' readonly='readonly' value='" . $row[2] . "'>";
```

But something even better would be to apply the row values to variables inside the loop:

```
$nombre = $row['usuario.nombre'];
$apellidos = $row['usuario.apellidos'];
$titulo = $row['incidencias.titulo'];
$descripcion = $row['incidencias.descripcion'];
//etc...
```

Comment: Thanks this was the problem i need to put '' in the value field thanks